# помогите разобратся с экземплярами класса

Tags: node.js

Я использую [MQL5-Connector-Js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mql5-connector-js) для того что бы получать данные с двух терминалов МТ5.

Код подключения к первому терминалу:

```
firstBrocker = require('mql5-connector-js')

new firstBrocker.ConfigContext({
  host_ip: "127.0.0.1", // server ip
  protocol: "tcp", // transfer protocol
  port1: 3033, // push socket port
  port2: 3034, // pull socket port
  port3: 3035, // publisher socket port
  timeout_ms: 1000 // wait for messages from server until timeout
}).init();

exports.getBid = (symbol, callback)=>{
  firstBrocker.SymbolInfo.bid(symbol).then(price => {
    callback(price)
    console.log(symbol + "Bid price : " + price)
  });
}

exports.getAsk = (symbol, callback) =>{
  firstBrocker.SymbolInfo.ask(symbol).then(price => {
    callback(price)
    console.log(ffirstBrockerf.ConfigContext.toString());
  })
}
```

Код подключения ко второму:

```
const secondBrocker = require('mql5-connector-js')

 new secondBrocker.ConfigContext({
  host_ip: "127.0.0.1", // server ip
  protocol: "tcp", // transfer protocol
  port1: 3036, // push socket port
  port2: 3037, // pull socket port
  port3: 3038, // publisher socket port
  timeout_ms: 1000 // wait for messages from server until timeout
}).init();

exports.getBid = (symbol, callback)=>{
  secondBrocker.SymbolInfo.bid(symbol).then(price => {
    callback(price)
    console.log(symbol + "Bid price : " + price)
  });
}

exports.getAsk = (symbol, callback) =>{
  secondBrocker.SymbolInfo.ask(symbol).then(price => {
    callback(price)
    console.log(secondBrocker.ConfigContext.toString());
  })
}
```

но первый и второй подключается к портам первого. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: почитайте исходники библиотеки, она, на самом деле, не учитывает то, что может быть больше одного коннекта https://github.com/JamshedAlamQaderi/mql5-connector-js/blob/master/src/socket_server.ts#L38, коннект к сокету существует в единственном экземпляре (кто из них успел раньше)

Comment: в nodejs модули кэшируются после первой загрузки, так что в качестве костыля можно попробовать перед каждым `require('mql5-connector-js')` делать удаление этого модуля из `require.cache`

Comment: @nörbörnën К сожалению это не помогло

Comment: с вероятностью 95 процентов мой совет должен был сработать. или вы не правильно зачистили кэш (это я не могу проверить так как не могу подключиться к mql-серверу), или 5 процентов сыграли. если последнее то форкните библиотеку и допишите что нужно, код там вполне понятно написан.

Comment: `delete require.cache['mql5-connector-js'];
const secondBrocker = require('mql5-connector-js')`  Вот так я зачистил кэш. Это правильно?

Comment: нет. распечатайте, чтобы посмотреть что там. в вашем случае нужно что-то вроде такого https://pastebin.com/WaSu9YgN

Comment: Да, так вроде удаляет. Когда я вывожу в консоль х до удаления показывает все подключенные файлы, а после удаления все но без mql5-connector-js. Но когда я вывожу ConfigContext.toString() значение портов берется все ровно с инициализации класса библиотеки а не те что задал я `class ConfigContext {
    constructor(config = {
        protocol: "tcp",
        host_ip: "127.0.0.1",
        port1: 3033,
        port2: 3034,
        port3: 3035,
        timeout_ms: 1000
    }) {
        this.config = config;
    }
    init() {......`

Comment: нет, это не так! https://replit.com/@norbornen/LegitimateImpureBoards#index.js, https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaxZz.jpg

Comment: Все получилось. Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Библиотека [`mql5-connector-js`](https://github.com/JamshedAlamQaderi/mql5-connector-js) написана немного странно: при создании объекта класса [ConfigContext](https://github.com/JamshedAlamQaderi/mql5-connector-js/blob/master/src/config_context.ts#L12) и последующем вызове метода .init ["создаётся"](https://github.com/JamshedAlamQaderi/mql5-connector-js/blob/master/src/config_context.ts#L28) соединение с внешним сервисом, но если до этого соединение было создано - оно переиспользуется и при этом переданные параметры соединения игнорируются.

Я могу предложить два способа как изменить такое поведение библиотеки:

1. форкнуть проект и написать иначе код, мешающий созданию второго соединения
2. перед созданием второго соединения выкинуть из памяти nodejs всё, что она знала о ранее подключёной `require` библиотеке. это не нарушит поведение ранее созданного ConfigContext при этом позволит создать новый ConfigContext с новым соединением.

Пример реализации п.2:

#### Первое соединение, файл `f.js`

```
// удаление информации о подключении библиотеки из require.cache
Object.keys(require.cache || {}).forEach((x) => {
  if (x.includes('mql5-connector-js')) {
    delete require.cache[x];
  }
});

const { ConfigContext, SymbolInfo } = require('mql5-connector-js')

const context = new ConfigContext({
  host_ip: "127.0.0.1", // server ip
  protocol: "tcp", // transfer protocol
  port1: 3033, // push socket port
  port2: 3034, // pull socket port
  port3: 3035, // publisher socket port
  timeout_ms: 1000 // wait for messages from server until timeout
});
context.init();

exports.printContext = () => {
  console.log(context);
}
```

#### Второе соединение, файл `s.js`

```
// удаление информации о подключении библиотеки из require.cache
Object.keys(require.cache || {}).forEach((x) => {
  if (x.includes('mql5-connector-js')) {
    delete require.cache[x];
  }
});

const { ConfigContext, SymbolInfo } = require('mql5-connector-js')

const context = new ConfigContext({
  host_ip: "127.0.0.1", // server ip
  protocol: "tcp", // transfer protocol
  port1: 3036, // push socket port
  port2: 3037, // pull socket port
  port3: 3038, // publisher socket port
  timeout_ms: 1000 // wait for messages from server until timeout
});
context.init();

exports.printContext = () => {
  console.log(context);
}
```

#### Первое и второе соединение в файле `index.js`

```
const first = require('./f');
const second = require('./s');

console.log('FIRST');
first.printContext();
console.log('SECOND');
second.printContext();
process.exit(0);
```

#### Результат запуска

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]